# Structs and unions: which is better from a performance point of view? Passing the parameter by value or pointer?

Tags: c, performance, pointers, constants

It's probably a silly question, but it makes me slightly quibble every time I want to "optimize" the passage of heavy arguments (such as structure for example) to a function that just reads them. I hesitate between passing a pointer:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} Foo;

int sum(struct Foo *foo_struct)
{
    return foo_struct->x + foo_struct->y + foo_struct->z;
}
```

Or a constant:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} Foo;

int sum(const struct Foo foo_struct)
{
    return foo_struct.x + foo_struct.y + foo_struct.z;
}
```

The pointers are intended not to copy the data but just to send its address, which costs almost nothing.

For constants, it probably varies between compilers or optimization levels, although I don't know how a constant pass is optimized; if it is, then the compiler probably does a better job than I do.

From a performance point of view only (even if it is negligible in my examples), what is the preferred way of doing things?

Comment: inline the functions and look at the generated assembler code.

Comment: @wildplasser do not inline as you will miss the difference

Comment: Calculate how long it takes to run each a billion times then compare the difference.

Comment: Asked this 3 years ago on Quora, but nobody would give me numbers quick so I ended up benchmarking it myself https://www.quora.com/Whats-a-good-heuristic-for-deciding-whether-to-accept-a-readonly-struct-by-value-or-by-address-in-C/answer/Petr-Skocik . Less than 4-`int` structs go faster by value on x86-64, pointers are faster for structs that are larger than that.

Comment: @PSkocik I think that's because small structs get passed in registers rather than doing `memcpy()`

Comment: @Barmar I guess that + sometimes the `&` can cause a memory spill of a struct that's already in registers. I don't remember what the exact benchmark was, but it does correspond to the threshold at which things change from passing by register to passing by memory (the exact rules for that are dictated by the ABI).

Comment: If you pass either by a pointer -- it won't make any difference at all (unless the total `union` or `struct` size is less than the `sizeof (a_pointer)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structs, much like arrays, are containers of data. Every time you work with a container, you will have its data layed out in a contiguous block of memory. The container itself is identified by its starting address, and every single time you operate with it, your program will need to do low level pointer arithmetic through dedicated instructions in order to apply an offset to get from the starting address to the desired field (or element in case of arrays). The only things that a compiler needs to know to work with a struct are (roughly):

1. Its starting address in memory.
2. The offset of each field.
3. The size of each field.

A compiler can optimize code working on structs in the same way if the struct is passed as pointer or not, and we'll see how in a moment. What's different though, it's ***how*** the struct is passed to each function.

First let me make one thing clear: the `const` qualifier is not useful to understand the difference between passing a structure as pointer or by value. It merely tells the compiler that inside the function the value of the parameter itself will not be modified. Performance difference between passing as value or as pointer is not affected in general by `const`. The `const` keyword only becomes useful for other kinds of optimizations, not this one.

The main difference between these two signatures:

```
void first(const struct mystruct x);
void second(struct mystruct *x);
```

is that the first function will expect **the whole struct** to be passed as parameter, which therefore means copying the whole structure on the stack right before calling the function. The second function however only needs a pointer to the structure, and therefore the argument can be passed as **a single value** on the stack, or in a register like it's usually done in x86-64.

Now, to better understand what happens, let's analyze the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct mystruct {
    unsigned a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k;
};

unsigned long __attribute__ ((noinline)) first(const struct mystruct x) {
    unsigned long total = x.a;
    total += x.b;
    total += x.c;
    total += x.d;
    total += x.e;
    total += x.f;
    total += x.g;
    total += x.h;
    total += x.i;
    total += x.j;
    total += x.k;

    return total;
}

unsigned long __attribute__ ((noinline)) second(struct mystruct *x) {
    unsigned long total = x->a;
    total += x->b;
    total += x->c;
    total += x->d;
    total += x->e;
    total += x->f;
    total += x->g;
    total += x->h;
    total += x->i;
    total += x->j;
    total += x->k;

    return total;
}

int main (void) {
    struct mystruct x = {0};
    scanf("%u", &x.a);

    unsigned long v = first(x);
    printf("%lu\n", v);

    v = second(&x);
    printf("%lu\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

The `__attribute__ ((noinline))` is just to avoid automatic inlining of the function, which for testing purposes is very simple and therefore will probably get inlined with `-O3`.

Let's now compile and disassemble the result with the help of `objdump`.

#### No optimizations

Let's first compile without optimizations and see what happens:

1. This is how `main()` calls `first()`:

   ```
     86a:   48 89 e0                mov    rax,rsp
     86d:   48 8b 55 c0             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x40]
     871:   48 89 10                mov    QWORD PTR [rax],rdx
     874:   48 8b 55 c8             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x38]
     878:   48 89 50 08             mov    QWORD PTR [rax+0x8],rdx
     87c:   48 8b 55 d0             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x30]
     880:   48 89 50 10             mov    QWORD PTR [rax+0x10],rdx
     884:   48 8b 55 d8             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28]
     888:   48 89 50 18             mov    QWORD PTR [rax+0x18],rdx
     88c:   48 8b 55 e0             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
     890:   48 89 50 20             mov    QWORD PTR [rax+0x20],rdx
     894:   8b 55 e8                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
     897:   89 50 28                mov    DWORD PTR [rax+0x28],edx
     89a:   e8 81 fe ff ff          call   720 <first>
   ```

   And this is the function itself:

   ```
    0000000000000720 <first>:
     720:   55                      push   rbp
     721:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
     724:   8b 45 10                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x10]
     727:   89 c0                   mov    eax,eax
     729:   48 89 45 f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
     72d:   8b 45 14                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x14]
     730:   89 c0                   mov    eax,eax
     732:   48 01 45 f8             add    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
     736:   8b 45 18                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x18]
     739:   89 c0                   mov    eax,eax
     ... same stuff happening over and over ...
     783:   48 01 45 f8             add    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
     787:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
     78b:   5d                      pop    rbp
     78c:   c3                      ret
   ```

   It's quite obvious that **the whole structure is being copied on the stack before calling the function**.

   The function then takes each value in the struct looking at each value contained in the struct on the stack each time (`DWORD PTR [rbp + offset]`).
2. This is how `main()` calls `second()`:

   ```
     8bf:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    rax,[rbp-0x40]
     8c3:   48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
     8c6:   e8 c2 fe ff ff          call   78d <second>
   ```

   And this is the function itself:

   ```
    000000000000078d <second>:
     78d:   55                      push   rbp
     78e:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
     791:   48 89 7d e8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rdi
     795:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
     799:   8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax]
     79b:   89 c0                   mov    eax,eax
     79d:   48 89 45 f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
     7a1:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
     7a5:   8b 40 04                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax+0x4]
     7a8:   89 c0                   mov    eax,eax
     ... same stuff happening over and over ...
     81f:   48 01 45 f8             add    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
     823:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
     827:   5d                      pop    rbp
     828:   c3                      ret
   ```

   You can see that the argument is passed as a pointer instead of being copied on the stack, which is only two very simple instructions (`lea` + `mov`). *However*, since now the function has to work with a pointer using the `->` operator, we see that every single time a value in the struct needs to be accessed, memory needs to be dereferenced *two* times instead of one (first to get the pointer to the structure from the stack, then to get the value at the specified offset in the struct).

It *may seem* that there is no real difference between the two functions, since the linear number of instructions (linear in terms of struct members) that was required to load the struct on the stack in the first case is still required to dereference the pointer another time in the second case.

We are talking about optimization though, and it makes no sense to not optimize the code. Let's see what happens if we do.

#### With optimizations

In reality, when working with a `struct`, we don't really care where it is in memory (stack, heap, data segment, whatever). As long as we know where it starts, it all boils down to applying the same simple pointer arithmetic to access the fields. This *always* needs to be done, regardless of where the structure resides or whether it was dynamically allocated or not.

If we optimize the code above with `-O3`, we now see the following:

1. This is how `main()` calls `first()`:

   ```
     61a:   48 83 ec 30             sub    rsp,0x30
     61e:   48 8b 44 24 30          mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x30]
     623:   48 89 04 24             mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],rax
     627:   48 8b 44 24 38          mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x38]
     62c:   48 89 44 24 08          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],rax
     631:   48 8b 44 24 40          mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x40]
     636:   48 89 44 24 10          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],rax
     63b:   48 8b 44 24 48          mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x48]
     640:   48 89 44 24 18          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18],rax
     645:   48 8b 44 24 50          mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x50]
     64a:   48 89 44 24 20          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20],rax
     64f:   8b 44 24 58             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x58]
     653:   89 44 24 28             mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x28],eax
     657:   e8 74 01 00 00          call   7d0 <first>
   ```

   And this is the function itself:

   ```
    00000000000007d0 <first>:
     7d0:   8b 44 24 0c             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0xc]
     7d4:   8b 54 24 08             mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
     7d8:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     7db:   8b 44 24 10             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
     7df:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     7e2:   8b 54 24 14             mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x14]
     7e6:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     7e9:   8b 54 24 18             mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x18]
     7ed:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     7f0:   8b 44 24 1c             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x1c]
     7f4:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     7f7:   8b 44 24 20             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x20]
     7fb:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     7fe:   8b 54 24 24             mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x24]
     802:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     805:   8b 54 24 28             mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x28]
     809:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     80c:   8b 44 24 2c             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x2c]
     810:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     813:   8b 44 24 30             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x30]
     817:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     81a:   c3                      ret
   ```
2. This is how `main()` calls `second()`:

   ```
     671:   48 89 df                mov    rdi,rbx
     674:   e8 a7 01 00 00          call   820 <second>
   ```

   And this is the function itself:

   ```
    0000000000000820 <second>:
     820:   8b 47 04                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x4]
     823:   8b 17                   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rdi]
     825:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     828:   8b 47 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x8]
     82b:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     82e:   8b 57 0c                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rdi+0xc]
     831:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     834:   8b 57 10                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x10]
     837:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     83a:   8b 47 14                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x14]
     83d:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     840:   8b 47 18                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x18]
     843:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     846:   8b 57 1c                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x1c]
     849:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     84c:   8b 57 20                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x20]
     84f:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     852:   8b 47 24                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x24]
     855:   48 01 c2                add    rdx,rax
     858:   8b 47 28                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x28]
     85b:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
     85e:   c3                      ret
   ```

It should now be clear which code is better. The compiler successfully identified that all it needs in both cases is to know where the beginning of the structure is, and then it can just apply the same simple math to determine the position of each field. Whether the address is on the stack or somewhere else, it does not really matter.

In fact, in the `first()` case we see all fields being accessed through `[rsp + offset]`, meaning that some address on the stack itself (`rsp`) is used to calculate the position of the fields, while in the `second()` case we see `[rdi + offset]`, meaning that the address passed as parameter (in `rdi`) is used instead. The offsets though are still the same.

So what's the difference now between the two functions? In terms of function code itself, basically none. In terms of parameter passing, the `first()` function still needs the struct passed by value, and therefore even with optimizations enabled, the whole structure still needs to be copied on the stack, therefore we can see that **the `first()` function is way heavier and adds a lot of code in the caller**.

As I previously said, a compiler can optimize code working on structs in the same way if the struct is passed as pointer or not. However, as we just saw, the way the structure is passed makes a *big* difference in the caller.

One could argue that the `const` qualifier for the `first()` function could ring a bell for the compiler and make it understand that there is really no need to copy the data on the stack, and the caller could just pass a pointer. However the compiler should strictly adhere to the calling convention dictated by the ABI for a given signature, instead of going out of its way to optimize the code. After all, it's not really the compiler's fault in this case, but the programmer's fault.

---

So, to answer your question:

> From a performance point of view only (even if it is negligible in my examples), what is the preferred way of doing things?

The preferred way is definitely to pass a pointer, and not the `struct` itself.

Comment: It's interesting that `const` doesn't make a difference. If the object isn't being modified, there's no need for a copy, so it could pass a pointer instead.

Comment: @Barmar from my experience GCC will never do that (pass a pointer when the function signature requires the value). That's however true, it's a further optimization that *could* be done.

Comment: @Barmar Even if it was modified, I guess with permission from the ABI, the caller could pass a pointer above a certain threshold and an on-deman copy could then be created in the callee if it turned out to be necessary (values modified and/or address taken).

Comment: Right, forgot about the ABI -- we need to ensure that callers and callees are compatible even when compiled with different compilers. Is there an optimization if the function is `static`?

Comment: @Barmar that's an interesting question. I'd bet on a "no" though.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way of doing things is to measure, not guess.  Code up small prototypes of each approach, then instrument and profile them extensively.  *Quantify* exactly how much of a runtime hit you take by passing a `struct` of a particular size by value vs. a pointer *and accessing its contents*.  Remember, if you pass a pointer, you'll have to do a dereference operation to access each member, which may negate any savings you gained by not passing a full copy (after all, you may only pass it once but access it many times in a single function call).  And you'll have to do this for every platform you want to support, because the answer will be different between different architectures.

Unless you are failing to meet a hard performance requirement, then do what best conveys the intent of the code.  If the function is not supposed to modify the contents of the struct type, then favor passing it by value instead of using a pointer.

And, finally, it's not the 1980s anymore.  Unless you're in an embedded environment or a mobile app that's trying to not suck the battery dry, you really shouldn't worry about performance at this level.  Focus on higher-level design issues.  Are you using the right algorithms and data structures?  Are you doing needless I/O?  Are you making these function calls a lot (as in a tight loop), or do they happen once over the lifetime of the program?

Comment: The preferred way of doing things is to understand them. Measuring is second, because measuring can only inform about the particular circumstances measured, whereas theory, specifications, and logic can inform generally.

Answer (score 1):

Every optimizing compiler will generate (sometimes almost) exactly the same code.

The only difference will be the invocation (ie function call). Structs are passed by the value and the whole struct has to be placed on stack (in typical implementation) when the argument of the function is not the pointer to the struct.

https://godbolt.org/z/Fx5tvG

The function call when passing by the pointer:

```
x:                                      # @x
        mov     edi, offset Foo
        jmp     sum                     # TAILCALL
```

The function call when passed by the value:

```
y:                                      # @y
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 416
        lea     rbx, [rsp + 208]
        mov     esi, offset Foo
        mov     edx, 208
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    memcpy
        mov     ecx, 26
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     rsi, rbx
        rep movsq es:[rdi], [rsi]
        call    sum1
        add     rsp, 416
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

The difference is obvious.

The functions are:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y[50];
    int z;
} Foo;

int __attribute__((noinline)) sum(struct Foo *foo_struct);
int __attribute__((noinline)) sum1(const struct Foo foo_struct);

int x()
{
    return sum(&Foo);
}

int y()
{
    return sum1(Foo);
}
```

For the rest of the code please follow the godbolt link

Answer (score 0):

Without optimization, `gcc 9.2` compiles the pointer version to:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+4]
    add     edx, eax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+8]
    add     eax, edx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

and the `const` version to:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     rdx, rdi
    mov     eax, esi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rdx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
    add     edx, eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    add     eax, edx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Passing a `const` means that the entire `struct` must be transferred to the stack frame of the function, while passing a pointer means that only enough room for the pointer needs to be allocated in the stack frame, no matter how large the `struct` is. Because of this, the pointer version will certainly be more memory efficient. I think it's possible that accessing the data through the pointer might be slower than accessing it within the stack frame if the pointer points far away (making the `struct` version potentially faster), but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: What is far away?

Comment: comparing not optimized code does not make any sense

Comment: In a land, far, far, away there once lived a pointer named foo...

Comment: @P__J__ You'll have to buy the book.

Comment: @FiddlingBits maybe cursed?

Comment: `but I'm not sure about that` if you are not sure you should test it with the data located *`far away`*

Comment: @P__J__ Far away as in, e.g., in a different cache level or no longer cached at all.